# How to limit ftp speed

Tags: linux, ftp, limit, bandwidth

I have multiple users on a server. They upload and download their files through FTP. Sometimes some heavy transfer causes high load on the server. I am wondering, if there is any way to limit the ftp speed to avoid high load.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Some FTP servers have builtin support for that. Which is yours? Is CPU, network bandwith or disk access bandwidth the issue here? You could also `nice` and `ionice -c 3` your FTP server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to limit ftp speed:

In the `/etc/proftpd.conf` insert this line:

```
TransferRate RETR,STOR,APPE,STOU 2000
```

This will limit ftp speed to 2 megabyte per second.

After changing the file you should restart the proftpd service:

```
/etc/init.d/proftpd restart
```

Comment: I know this is old but hopefully it helps anyone who finds it. The answer above is 100% correct, but can be slightly misleading. Be aware of this when using this directive. [Online Manual Page](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_TransferRate.html "Online manual page") From proftpd's configuration directives document page, in the Description section. > Note that this limit only applies to a single connection, and not to the overall transfer rate of the server.

Answer (score 3):

The keyword is **bandwidth management** and the Linux Kernel has direct support of it. I dealed with this long time ago and have forgotten much about that but there is a great online book that covers the topic extensively. It's called

- **[Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control](http://www.lartc.org/)**.

To get a foretaste of what you want to achieve take a look at

- **[Chapter 9. Queueing Disciplines for Bandwidth Management](http://www.lartc.org/lartc.html#LARTC.QDISC)**.

Perhaps there are (software) servers which support bandwidth control directly!?

---

**Supplement**:

- In the [pureftpd FAQ](http://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/doc/FAQ) it is explained how to enable bandwidth limitation on the system level. On the first sight it seems to be applicable to other ftp servers as well.
- There is another freely available book called

  [**How to Accelerate Your Internet:** A Practical Guide to Bandwidth Management and Optimisation Using Open Source Software](http://bwmo.net/index.html)

  that deals with the topic. At first glance it seems to worth a look.